# fetch() not returning the right JSON

Tags: php, react-native

I'm trying to create a feed using React Native. I get the correct data with Ajax, but in React Native, I get something completely different.

[image]

Here's what the URL returns when you go to it in your browser

[image]

The PHP script has `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the top.

Here is my function to get the JSON.

```
getPostData()
{
    fetch('https://url.com/api/globalfeed.php?skip=0' + '&key=' + this.state.user,
    {
        headers:
        {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then((response) =>
    {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

Here is my PHP

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// Compile all the data for the post to return it.
        array_push($toReturn, [
            'PostID' => $feedPost['PostID'],
            'PostAuthor' => $feedPost['PostAuthor'],
            'PostAuthorName' => $poster->data['FirstName'] . ' ' . $poster->data['LastName'],
            'PostProfilePic' => $poster->data['ProfilePicture'],
            'PostText' => embedEmojis($feedPost['PostText']),
            'PostIsImage' => $feedPost['PostIsImage'],
            'PostImageURL' => $feedPost['PostImageURL'],
            'PostTime' => $feedPost['PostTime'],
            'PostTimeFormatted' => timeElapsed('@'.$feedPost['PostTime']),
            'PostLiked' => $liked,
            'PostLikes' => $feedPost['PostLikes'],
            'PostComments' => $cAr,
            'Verified' => $poster->data['Verified'],
            'Owned' => $owned
        ]);

    die(json_encode($toReturn));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Response object you get from fetch() contains much more than just the body, as you can see. Use the [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) function to read the body and parse it as JSON.

Comment: I added json() to response and got this

https://i.gyazo.com/cc0802b9f76f0e65703164c3a76a774d.png

Comment: `json()` returns yet another promise that you have to use `.then` on. Stop guessing and read the documentation.